# How to use BeautifulSoup to get content between<hr class = 'calibre2'> ... <hr class="calibre2" />

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
<hr class="calibre2" />
<h3 class="calibre5">-ability</h3> (in nouns 构成名词) ： <br class="calibre4" />
<blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span class="italic">◊ capability 能力 </span></p></blockquote>

<blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span class="italic">◊ responsibility 责任 </span></p></blockquote>

<hr class="calibre2" />
<h3 class="calibre5">-ibility</h3> (in nouns 构成名词) ： <br class="calibre4" />
<blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span class="italic">◊ capability 能力 </span></p></blockquote>

<blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span class="italic">◊ responsibility 责任 </span></p></blockquote>

<hr class="calibre2" />
```

above this is my part of my soup, and I want to get content between the two `<hr>`, because hr is not a close tag, so I couldn't use some simple method, I have think if I can use find_next_elements, but How can let him stop, when he see `<hr class = 'calibre2'>`, so I can get those content, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over all `hr` elements and use [`.find_next_siblings()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) to iterate over the next sibling elements. Then, if you meet `hr`, break the loop:

```
for hr in soup.find_all("hr", class_="calibre2"):
    for item in hr.find_next_siblings():
        if item.name == "hr":
            break

        print(item)
    print("-----")
```

Comment: How can I express you give me the big help, I use a whole morning, want to fix the problem, you survived me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hello, I want to know how to get pure text  between  the <hr class="calibre2" />, because hr is not a close tag, so I couldn't use tag.txt directly, so I use try and except method, in the try when is tag I use tag.txt and except if is a string, I just add into a string, but when I get the result is not good, some content lose, and tag still in there, so can you tell me how to deal with the don't have tag close and I want to get pure text issues. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the hr and calibre2 class in conjunction with find_all_next 
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

testStr = """
<hr class="calibre2" />
<h3 class="calibre5">-ability</h3> (in nouns 构成名词) ： <br class="calibre4" />
<blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span class="italic">◊ capability 能力 </span></p></blockquote>

<blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span class="italic">◊ responsibility 责任 </span></p></blockquote>

<hr class="calibre2" />
<h3 class="calibre5">-ibility</h3> (in nouns 构成名词) ： <br class="calibre4" />
<blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span class="italic">◊ capability 能力 </span></p></blockquote>

<blockquote class="calibre6"><p class="calibre_1"><span class="italic">◊ responsibility 责任 </span></p></blockquote>

<hr class="calibre2" />
""";
soup = BeautifulSoup(testStr, 'lxml')
hrTag = soup.hr

nextTags = hrTag.find_all_next()

content = []

for item in nextTags:
    # check if we have reached the second calibre2 hr
    print("Name %s ; Class %s" % (item.name, item['class'][0]))
    if item.name == 'hr' and item['class'][0] == 'calibre2':
        break
    content.append(item)
print(content)
```

Comment: Thank you for tell me, but in my windows I couldn't use beautifulsoup(...,'lxml'), they tell me to install tree. But When I want to install xml, I couldn't use pip method. But I will try and learn your code.

Comment: Hello, I want to know if you have method to get pure text between the two hr tags, because the tr tag is not close tag, so I couldn't directly get the pure text in it. Even I try use try and except method want to get pure text, the result is not good. Do you have any method to add a close tag outside the open <hr> so , I could directly use tag.txt get my desire things, thank you.