# Is there something similar to the list function for PHP in Python?

Tags: python, variables

I am aware there is a way of always setting multiple variables of a list or dictionary by initializing variables by a comma and setting variable with the list / dict that is wanted.

Example is that I have a description that I split so many times due to redundancy and I want to make the variables easily accessible.

```
spl_desc = desc.replace("&nbsp;", "").split("<hr>")
part_one = spl_desc[0].split()
part_two = spl_desc[1].split()
```

And then both parts are split again as the first variable of the second split for both first parts are the exact same and the second part is slightly different but most of the time the same.

```
redundant_var_one_part_one = part_one[0]
almost_redundant_des_one = part_one[1]
redundant_var_one_part_two = part_two[0]
almost_redundant_des_two = part_two[1]
```

Bonus question to this, would it be possible to set those variables again directly while splitting those variables?

**EDIT QUESTION**
In PHP the above would look like this

```
list(redundant_var_one_part_one, almost_redundant_des_one) = part_one;
list(redundant_var_one_part_two, almost_redundant_des_two) = part_two;
```

Each variable is set "inline" and avoids setting every item in the array.
Bonus question example. In PHP would be something like

```
list(part_one, part_two) = explode(str_replace("&nbsp;", "", desc), "<hr>");
```

Comment: If you want to "split" by the horizontal rule in html then see this:  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38680626/how-to-use-beautifulsoup-to-get-content-betweenhr-class-calibre2-hr-c

Comment: I don't understand this question. What is your problem?  Maybe show example data, result which you get, and result which you expect.

Comment: I don't understand `bonus question`. Maybe first try and later ask question.

Comment: I don't know what you try to do but usually it is better to keep results on list because then you can use `for`-loop and make code shorter and simpler -  `parts = []` , `for item in spl_desc: parts.append( item.split() )`. And later `for item in parts: print(item[0], item[1])`

Comment: Edited the question. @forus I understand. Sorry I did not put this in there, I want the functionality to stay inline without any looping or special functions. In a way it would be extra redundant instead of just picking the parts I need to set in my dictionary immediately after. This looks like it would work, I have edited the question for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're asking for is just implicit in Python assignment:

```
a, b = [item_one, item_two]
```

e.g.:

```
>>> a, b = ["foo", "bar"]
>>> a
'foo'
>>> b
'bar'
```

or:

```
>>> some_vars = [23, 34]
>>> a, b = some_vars
>>> a
23
>>> b
34
```

Comment: Oh wow nice. Is there a name for this? @Matt Thanks man!

Comment: Not sure if it has an official name, but if you call it "list assignment", Python devs likely know what you mean.